# Sorting Logic within same collection

Tags: c#

[image]

hello,
I am trying to figure out some logic on how this is done. i have a collection of persons, each person can report to another person, or he can report to no one (null), what i would like to do say for example i want to edit a person to whom he reports to, for example as in image i want to edit person (4), i want to return a list of employees that he could be assigned to (in green), and exclude the ones that he could not be assigned to (marked x red).

i tried creating different lists and looping through each checking if the list where report to has any value, but i feel it is messy a does not include the flexibility to search more than two levels below the selected person.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Person>> GetAllEmployeesThatCanBeReportedToAsync(int currentPersonid)
    {
        bool DoesAnyPersonReportToHim = context.HR_Emp_EmploymentDetails.Where(p => p.ReportsTo == currentPersonid).Any();
        List<Person> ListofPersonstoexclude = new List<Person>();

        //If No one reports to Him. 
        //returm All (Except Current) 
        if (DoesAnyPersonReportToHim == false)
        {
            var result = context.Persons.Where(p => p.PersonId != currentPersonid).ToListAsync();
            return await result;
        }
        //If some Persons reports to Him. 
        //returm All Persons (Except Current) 
        //And (Except Persons that Report to Him) and (Except Persons that Report to Persons that Report to Him)..est.
        else
        {
            //find Persons that report to him.
            List<Person> LevelOneThatReportToHim =
                context.Person.Where(p => p.ReportsTo == currentPersonid).ToList();
            List<Person> LevelTwo = new List<Person>();

            ListofPersonstoexclude.AddRange(LevelOneThatReportToHim);

            foreach (var item in LevelOneThatReportToHim)
            {
                if (context.Persons.Where(p => p.ReportsTo == item.HR_Emp_EmploymentDetailId).Any())
                {
                    var Person = context.Persons.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ReportsTo == item.PersonId);
                    LevelTwo.Add(Person);
                    ListofPersonstoexclude.Add(Person);
                }
            }

            if (LevelTwo.Any())
            {
                foreach (var item in LevelTwo)
                {
                    if (context.Persons.Where(p => p.ReportsTo == item.PersonId).Any())
                    {
                        var Person = context.Persons.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ReportsTo == item.PersonId);
                        ListofPersonstoexclude.Add(Person);
                    }
                }
            }

            List<Person> result = context.Persons
                .Where(p => p.PersonId != currentPersonid).ToList();

            foreach (var Person1 in ListofPersonstoexclude)
            {
                result.RemoveAll(Person2 => Person2.PersonId == Person1.PersonId);
            }

            return result;
        }



    }
```

Comment: This would be a good `recursion` exercise.

Comment: [Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)

Comment: @Jimi: Why breadth-first, specifically?  Depth-first seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Scott Hunter Not much of a difference here. I didn't look at the code (the OP may want to analyze a vertex before enqueuing). Anyway, Depth-first is also referenced in that link.

Comment: If you added Level indicator then you could simply filter on (x => x.Level > selected.Level &&  x.ParentID <> selected.ParentID)

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for logic, pseudo-code should suffice:

```
CanBeAssignedTo( root, assignee ):
    if root is empty or root == assignee:
        return []
    result = [root]
    Foreach child of root:
         append CanBeAssignedTo(child,assignee) to result
    return result
```